# QT unmet dependencies for smplayer

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, qt, smplayer

I was trying to upgrade `smplayer`, but `aptitude` tells that it's unable to solve the dependencies for `libqt5script5`

```
$>sudo aptitude dist-upgrade 
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libqt5script5{ab} 
The following packages will be upgraded:
  smplayer smtube 
2 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,846 kB of archives. After unpacking 3,191 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqt5script5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-2-1 which is a virtual package.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Remove the following packages:                       
1)     smplayer                                           
2)     smplayer-skins                                     
3)     smplayer-themes                                    
4)     smtube                                             

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
5)     libqt5script5 [Not Installed]
```

The `libqt5script5` package, however, depends on the `qtbase-abi-5-2-1` virtual package, so I can't install it. How can I fix this problem?

EDIT:
About the system

```
$>lsb_release -r
Release:    14.04
$>uname -r
3.13.0-91-generic
```

Comment: what version of Ubuntu are you using? read this thread http://askubuntu.com/questions/324818/correct-way-to-install-virtual-dependency

Comment: @JoKeR added info on the system on the question, but I don't know what to do with the link. It seems that there is nothing useful about my case.

Comment: Are you using the musescore ppa? If so you can either use ppa-purge on it & then install smplayer or keep the ppa & it's packages & not use smplayer

Comment: @doug It appears that I don't have the ppa, but I certainly have the application installed. However, I don't remember if I deleted the ppa just after installing the application or if instead I just installed it from a .deb. What do you suggest to do? I've just completely removed musicscore and run again `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade`, but the problem still remains.

Comment: If you have the ppa musescore & resultant  qt5 libs then you'll need to add back ppa & update sources, install ppa-purge & use it on the ppa. So ck. with `apt-cache policy musescore` , should be obvious if ppa version is installed

Comment: eureka! The problem is solved. Btw @doug you seem to know the issue very well. Why does it happen? Do you have any link related to this problem? Should I be able to install `MuseScore` again in the foreseeable future? Also, please add your answer so I can easily accept it.

Comment: @doug forgot to mention you

Comment: these issues may happen a lot when you add *staging* ppa that is not official from Ubuntu or install file from *.deb* ext. lots of interesting things might happen as you take all the responsibility on yourself knowing that it might harm your system to work properly. To avoid this in the future when adding something to the system in an unofficial way you should know what you're doing.

Comment: this is a bit different but you might read this topic on PPAs http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa